# Difficulty in selecting the checkbox by the user

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

With jQuery in a loop, I display the list of networks as follows

```
        var networks;
        window.addEventListener('networksEvent' , event => {
            networks = event.detail.networks;
            $.each(networks, function( index, network ) {
                $('#networlist').append('<div class="custom-control custom-control-sm custom-radio">'+
                   '<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="'+network.id+'">'+
                    '<label class="custom-control-label" for="'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>'+
            '</div>');
            });
        });
```

(i Send data to this page via `dispatchBrowserEvent‍` in livewire)

But the problem is that the user should be able to select a checkbox, but after selecting another previous checkbox is still selected

[image: see this picture]

what is problem?

Comment: First of all these are radio buttons not checkboxes. Make sure that all radio buttons share the same name attribute, e.g. <input type="radio" name="network" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not passing `name` attribute on the input field. Try following:

```js
var networks;
window.addEventListener('networksEvent' , event => {
    networks = event.detail.networks;
    $.each(networks, function( index, network ) {
        $('#networlist').append('<div class="custom-control custom-control-sm custom-radio">'+
            '<input type="radio" name="network" class="custom-control-input" id="'+network.id+'">'+
            '<label class="custom-control-label" for="'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>'+
    '</div>');
    });
});
```